# TypeScript does not properly check object properties

Tags: typescript

I have an object which has string and number property values. When I want to set value of certain field TypeScript fails at checking property types when using `indexOf` method for checking.

Here is example:

```
type TSomeObject = {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  count: number
}

const someFunction = (myObj: TSomeObject, field: keyof TSomeObject, newValue: string): TSomeObject => {
  if (field === 'title' || field === 'description') {
    myObj[field] = newValue
  }
  return myObj
}

const otherFunction = (myObj: TSomeObject, field: keyof TSomeObject, newValue: string): TSomeObject =>{
  const editableFields = ['title', 'description']
  if (editableFields.indexOf(field) >= 0) {
    // TypeScript error here
    myObj[field] = newValue
  }
  return myObj
}
```

See this example in [TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgygewLYQPICMBWEDGwoC8UA3gFBRTACWwANhAFxQDOwATlQHYDmANOVAAmEZjg5hqCTk1Yce-CjgQBXTsCadlSdBDakAvqVJLOrFsggAxVXipTCUABRIQGTE3gW3uYLygAzKghaQSYAawgQBH9YRBRvPD9OCAB3ADUAQ1plRhZ2Lm4ASg84tCwfQgA+EgEqGMdA4MFCAiIAcmo6CDaoAB9egKCQlvbhUXFJTjbCmooKFzcAbUaQgF0HZPSsnIFDCjYIYGU2TigFrAMjEzMEYAALXWtOW3siZ1csEq9yxMGm8Mi0Vi32wv02mWyuVkBWKwPiP3wBGqZEUUjMEEENAy6HoliGgmYDkWHRo9DafjaYzEVAkdimq1q9QxWJxVnxzAAdFxhAAPVD+Br4maVIgABhmKLmAHopbBwBA4NSJFBdGwEGwoA8DgJ5h9MMt8esiODthBdgIDkcTmc9QYgA).

While `someFunction` works perfectly fine, `otherFunction` fails with TypeScript error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I know it is related to `count` property which is of type `number`, but hey I checked which field am I editing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The type of editableFields is string[]. I tried to set the correct type, for example with: const editableFields: Array<'title' | 'description'> = ['title', 'description'], but that just causes indexOf not to work.

Comment: that playground link doesn't work

Comment: @jcalz Playground link is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are going on here.

---

One is that `editableFields` is inferred as `string[]`, which is too wide for your purposes.  Since TS3.4, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to infer narrower types for literals:

```
const editableFields = ['title', 'description'] as const;
// const editableFields: readonly ["title", "description"]
```

Now `editableFields` is a tuple whose members are known to be `"title"` and `"description"`.

---

Next, TypeScript doesn't take the result of `arr.indexOf(x) >= 0` to be a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) on the type of `x`.  So even if the test is `true`, the type of `x` is not narrowed to `typeof arr[number]` automatically.  This is just a limitation of TypeScript; not every possible way of testing for something can be detected by the compiler.  Luckily, TypeScript gives you the ability to make [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  In this case, you might want to make something like this:

```
declare function arrayContains<T extends U, U>(
  haystack: ReadonlyArray<T>, 
  needle: U
): needle is T;
```

(I'm using `ReadonlyArray` instead of `Array` because it's more general.  Every `Array` is a `ReadonlyArray` but not vice versa.  Yes, it's a weird name, since `ReadonlyArray` might not be read-only; perhaps `ReadonlyArray` should be `DefinitelyReadableButNotNecessarilyWritableArray` and `Array` should be `DefinitelyBothReadableAndWritableArray`.  Perhaps not.)

That's a generic user-defined type guard that takes a `haystack` array of some type `Array<T>`, and a `needle` of some type `U` which is wider than `T`, and if it returns `true`, the compiler understands that `needle is T`.  (It *also* thinks that `false` implies that `needle` is *not* `T`, which [might not always be desirable](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048).  In your case, since `T` and `U` will both be string literals or unions of them, it's not an issue.)

If we have an implementation for `arrayContains()`, we'd change the test to be this:

```
if (arrayContains(editableFields, field)) {
    myObj[field] = newValue; // no error now
}
```

So, let's implement `arrayContains()`.

---

Here's the next thing: [TypeScript's standard library's typings for `indexOf()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.4/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1125) is this:

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  indexOf(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): number;
}
```

That means the `needle` needs to be of the same type (`T`) as the elements of the `haystack`.  But you want your `needle` to be of a *wider* type (you're looking to see if a `string` is in an array of `"this" | "that"` elements).  So TypeScript will not let you just do this:

```
function arrayContains<T extends U, U>(haystack: ReadonlyArray<T>, needle: U): needle is T {
    return haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0; // error!
    //                      ~~~~~~ <-- U is not assignable to T
}
```

Luckily you can safely widen a `ReadonlyArray<T>` to a `ReadonlyArray<U>`, so you can write it like this:

```
function arrayContains<T extends U, U>(haystack: ReadonlyArray<T>, needle: U): needle is T {
    const widenedHaystack: ReadonlyArray<U> = haystack;
    return widenedHaystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0; 
}
```

And that works!  You could also, instead, just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to silence the compiler, as in:

```
function arrayContains<T extends U, U>(haystack: ReadonlyArray<T>, needle: U): needle is T {
    return haystack.indexOf(needle as T) >= 0; // assert
}
```

but I usually try to avoid assertions unless they are necessary, and here they are not.  It's up to you.

---

So let's put it all together:

```
function arrayContains<T extends U, U>(haystack: ReadonlyArray<T>, needle: U): needle is T {
    const widenedHaystack: ReadonlyArray<U> = haystack;
    return widenedHaystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0; 
}

function otherFunction(myObj: TSomeObject, field: keyof TSomeObject, newValue: string): TSomeObject {
    const editableFields = ['title', 'description'] as const;
    if (arrayContains(editableFields, field)) {
        myObj[field] = newValue
    }
    return myObj
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-Fug1EapMllsoXAkRHE5nKABrCmCgUIA)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks